# How to download NuGet packages programatically from .NET Core, .NET Standard projects

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard

I want to download Nuget packages programmatically from the .NET core/.NET Standard projects

We have some console apps that are tools NuGet packages and I want to download those and start them as a background process.

Comment: NuGet is open sourced, so you can use its API directly https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Client/4.2.0

Comment: You can also implement your tools as dotnet global tools, then use `dotnet tool install` to install them, so you don't have to figure out the nuget apis yourself.

Comment: @zivkan, thanks are donet global tools only for .NET core, can I multi-target them for both .NET Core and .NET Full?

Comment: I don't think you can multi-target, how would the dotnet cli know which one to put on your path? But you could certainly try targeting the .net framework. I have no idea if anything actually validates/forces it to be a netcoreapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to achieve it is by referring **NugetDownloader** Nuget package  in Project and use it to download any package programmatically(in dotnet core as well)

```
Install-Package NugetDownloader
```

[image: NuGet Badge]

Source code and help guide on the same is available at :
https://github.com/paraspatidar/NugetDownloader

Here is a quick sample on how to achieve it :

```cs
string packageName="Newtonsoft.json";
string version="10.2.1.0"; \\optional

\\initilize NugetEngine from NugetDownloader namespaces

NugetEngine nugetEngine = new NugetEngine();
nugetEngine.GetPackage(packageName, version).Wait();
```

sample client is also available at https://github.com/paraspatidar/NugetDownloader/tree/master/NugetDownloaderTestConsole

Alternately In case if you want to build your Nugetdownloader engine from scratch , then you might also refer https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/DotNet/PackageManager.cs as it has something similar implementation , but that too much of code understanding and extraction.